# SimpleDateFormat getHours() return incorrect value

Tags: java, android, simpledateformat

Why getHours() for "09:50" return 8?
Code:

```
SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("HH:mm");
Date date = sdf.parse("09:50");
int hours = date.getHours(); // return 8 instead of 9 ???
```

Comment: `getHours()` is deprecated. You shouldn't even be using it.

Comment: `SimpleDateFormat` is locale-sensitive, wouldn't your timezone be GMT-1? Also, consider using Joda TIme instead of Java's builtin date functions. For once, `SimpleDateFormat` is not thread safe, while Joda Time's `DateTimeFormatter` is.

Comment: do you want current time???

Comment: I cannot reproduce. I get 9.

Answer (score 0):

```
            Calendar prueba = Calendar.getInstance();

        prueba.set(2013, 1, 6, 10, 49, 32);

        int day = prueba.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH);
        int month = prueba.get(Calendar.MONTH);
        int year = prueba.get(Calendar.YEAR);
        int hours = prueba.get(Calendar.HOUR);
        int minutes = prueba.get(Calendar.MINUTE);
        int seconds = prueba.get(Calendar.SECOND);

        Log.v("printf", "Date: " + day + "/"
                                 + month + "/"
                                 + year + "\n");
        Log.v("printf", "Time: " + hours + ":"
                                 + minutes + ":"
                                 + seconds + "\n");
```

PD: Remember field Month from Calendar class begin by 0 (0-January, 1-February, ...)
PD2: I have personalize tag on filter logcat called "printf". Change that for your tag that you use.

Answer (score 0):

It seems your SimpleDateFormat may not have been set to the default time zone.
Calling:

```
sdf.setTimeZone(TimeZone.getDefault());
```

before parsing the literal should solve your problem.
I have tested the following code:

```
...
    public static final SimpleDateFormat CDfTimestamp = new SimpleDateFormat(
            "yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss");
...
    Date da1 = null;
    for (String dl1 : new String[] { "1970-01-01 12:34:56",
            "2016-01-01 12:34:56" }) {
        try {
            CDfTimestamp.setTimeZone(TimeZone.getTimeZone("GMT+05:00"));
            da1 = CDfTimestamp.parse(dl1);
            System.out.printf("parse GMT+05:00 %s -> %d %d %d (os=%d)\n", dl1, da1
                    .getHours(), da1.getMinutes(), da1.getSeconds(), CDfTimestamp
                    .getTimeZone().getOffset(0));
            CDfTimestamp.setTimeZone(TimeZone.getTimeZone("UTC"));
            da1 = CDfTimestamp.parse(dl1);
            System.out.printf("parse UTC       %s -> %d %d %d (os=%d)\n", dl1, da1
                    .getHours(), da1.getMinutes(), da1.getSeconds(), CDfTimestamp
                    .getTimeZone().getOffset(0));
            CDfTimestamp.setTimeZone(TimeZone.getDefault());
            da1 = CDfTimestamp.parse(dl1);
            System.out.printf("parse default   %s -> %d %d %d (os=%d)\n", dl1, da1
                    .getHours(), da1.getMinutes(), da1.getSeconds(), CDfTimestamp
                    .getTimeZone().getOffset(0));
        } catch (ParseException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
...
```

obtaining the following output:

```
parse GMT+05:00 1970-01-01 12:34:56 -> 8 34 56 (os=18000000)
parse UTC       1970-01-01 12:34:56 -> 13 34 56 (os=0)
parse default   1970-01-01 12:34:56 -> 12 34 56 (os=3600000)
parse GMT+05:00 2016-01-01 12:34:56 -> 8 34 56 (os=18000000)
parse UTC       2016-01-01 12:34:56 -> 13 34 56 (os=0)
parse default   2016-01-01 12:34:56 -> 12 34 56 (os=3600000)
```

Answer (score -3):

Date is deprecated. you should use calendar.

```
 SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("HH:mm");
 Date date = sdf.parse("09:50");
 Calendar cal = new GregorianCalendar();
cal.setTime(date);
int hours = cal.get(Calendar.HOR_OF_DAY);
```

Comment: Date is deprecated? That is a misleading and incorrect statement. Please correct this.