# dateFormat doesn't contain the parsed date

Tags: java, date, simpledateformat

Here is what I am doing :

```
SimpleDateFormat parserSDF = new SimpleDateFormat("EEE MMM dd HH:mm:ss zzzz yyyy", Locale.ENGLISH);
Date dateFormat = parserSDF.parse("Mon Nov 07 00:00:00 CEST 2016");
```

`dateFormat` should then contain Mon Nov 07 00:00:00 CET 2016, but here is what I get when logging it :

> Sun Nov 06 23:00:00 CET 2016

Why do I get this hour of difference?

Thank you.

Comment: CEST is one hour ahead of CET so they are the same time - the output is using your local settings.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

CEST stands for Central European Summer Time, which is the same as CET but with daylight saving time into effect. Use CET, like:

```
Date dateFormat = parserSDF.parse("Mon Nov 07 00:00:00 CET 2016");
```

Answer (score 1):

CEST stands for **Central European Summer Time** which is 1 hour after CET, so result is correct.

So if you go with:

```
Date dateFormat = parserSDF.parse("Mon Nov 07 00:00:00 CET 2016");
```

you'll get expected result.

Answer (score 1):

CEST = Central European Summer Time

Summer time is +1 hour to normal CET.
In November Summer time usually isn't used.

Answer (score 0):

the issue is probably a timezone issue:

```
SimpleDateFormat parserSDF = new SimpleDateFormat("EEE MMM dd HH:mm:ss zzzz yyyy", Locale.ENGLISH);
parserSDF.setTimeZone(TimeZone.getTimeZone("GMT"));
Date dateFormat = parserSDF.parse("Mon Nov 07 00:00:00 CEST 2016");
```

Set the timezone as shown above. The issue has been resolved here:
[Java SimpleDateFormat: an hour wrong](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14124701/java-simpledateformat-an-hour-wrong)